# How to load propertyDb for f2d files in local environment

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using [Forge extractor](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/master/README.md) in order to translate model into SVF format and load them in the local environment using Forge Viewer v7. I've selected both 3D Views and 2D Floor Plans from Revit for translation and I can see that they are converted successfully.

I am loading the 3D view using this method:

```
  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
  viewer.start("Resource/3D View/{3D} xxxxxx/{3D}.svf", options);
```

I can see that the properties for the elements can be loaded succesfully and I can view the properties/attributes for this element using the Properties Panel.
[image]

However, when I am loading a 2D Floor plan (f2d) file using this method:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () { 
viewer.start("2c627223-65bc-e4f4-6518-dda3dc1960dc_f2d/primaryGraphics.f2d", options);
```

The properties for elements can not be displayed correctly.[image]

May I know is there a way to also display properties for objects in 2D Floor Plan? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that extractor has been officially retired recently so we would not be supporting it going forward ...

Try other tools like [this](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bucketsmanager-desktop), [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/meet-forge-tools-hub-jamstackserverless-tools-download-derivatives-svf-and-view-models-offline) and [this](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-cli-utils) etc to download the SVFs

Coming back to the issues you were experiencing - apparently the property db was not loaded ... see your console output and check for any 404 errors for getting `object*.json` - these files are the property db...:

```
    attrs:   [path + "objects_attrs.json.gz"],
            values:  [path + "objects_vals.json.gz"],
            avs:     [path + "objects_avs.json.gz"],
            offsets: [path + "objects_offs.json.gz"],
            ids:     [path + "objects_ids.json.gz"]
```

Once you use a tool that downloads all the dependencies for f2d derivatives properly or implement the process correctly yourself then everything would be functioning properly again ...

Comment: Is it possible to reference/call the propertydb when trying to load f2d derivatives? I can see that the propertydb files were downloaded successfully inside Resource folder but they were not loaded

Comment: Yes try specify the path to them by passing `sharedPropertyDbPath` to the model load options - see sample code [here](https://github.com/dukedhx/viewer-iot-react-feathersjs/blob/master/src/client/app.js#L52)